# How to add datetime condition in django html file and how to use parentheses

Tags: python, html, django, datetime

I'm using Django, and there is an 'add' button inside the html file. I want to hide this button from users from Friday 1pm to Sunday. The condition is added as follows, but parentheses cannot be used in the if statement. Any other solution? Help me!

[views.py]

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date

def supporting(request):
    today = datetime.today()

    return render(request, 'supporting.html',
                    {'today': today})
```

[supporting.html]

```
{% if (today.weekday == 4 and today.hour > 13) or today.weekday >= 5 %} <button type="button">Add</button> {% endif %}
```

Comment: You don't need the parentheses, `and` has higher precedence than `or` in the tag anyway

Comment: You can just check it inside the views.py file and pass a boolean like True or False to render the button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see one issue that may be tripping you up.  In your view, try changing:

```
today = datetime.today()
```

to:

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
```

Then in the template you might try something like:

```
{% if today.weekday == 4 or today.hour > 13 %} <your button> {% elif today.weekday => 5 %} <your button> {% endif %}
```

No parenthesis needed, as Iain remarked.  Not sure what you're trying to achieve with the conditional checks -- you may want to break out "today.hour" into a separate check, or make it "and" instead of "or".